# Unable to Clear TextField in Appium Android Automation

Tags: appium-android

I used the below code:

```php
web.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a")); 
web.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);
```

This method almost worked, it cleared first, and is entering an alphabet a, dont know y, I tried `element.sendKeys(Keys.Delete);` but still no luck, attached is the screen after the method was executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWakk.png)

Answer (score 0):

The clear function should provide what you're looking for:

```
element.clear()
```

Documentation on this can be found in [the official Appium documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/element/actions/clear/).

Answer (score 0):

`element.clear()` would work but if you actually need to delete something you can use exactly what you have except like this

```
web.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a")); 
web.sendKeys(Keys.BACKSPACE);
```

no _ in `BACKSPACE`

keep in mind if you want to delete a characters before the cursor use `Keys.BACKSPACE`, to delete characters after the curser use `Keys.DELETE`